# How to select those records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table like this and I want to select those rows:

[image]

so if there are more than 3 records with speed=0 in a row (consecutive), it'll be selected.

Comment: any specfic logic behind this since I see 0 in the first row as well so that could not be used in the condition.

Comment: i think he wants consecutive rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name tn
WHERE

((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id+1 AND speed=0)>0 AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id+2 AND speed=0)>0) OR

((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id-1 AND speed=0)>0 AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id-2 AND speed=0)>0) OR

((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id+1 AND speed=0)>0 AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id=tn.id-1 AND speed=0)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table_name
where speed=0
and (select count(*) from table_name where speed=0) > 3
```

Comment: i think he wants consecutive rows